# Exception specification in declaration does not match previous declaration

Tags: c++, c++17

I compiled the file by g++ and clang++.
g++ has no any error and warning.
But clang++ has an error "exception specification in declaration does not match previous declaration".
By the way, if the file has no `throw()`, there has no any error and warning in clang++ output.
Which is correct for c++ spec, gcc or clang?

version:
g++: 7.4.0
clang++: 10.0.0

```
struct A {
  void g() throw () { }
  static void (A::*pmf)() throw ();
};

void (A::* A::pmf)() = &A::g;
```

Comment: @Chipster `pmf` isn't a static function, it's a static member variable.

Comment: What's the question? Which compiler is correct? is there a reason you don't just use a type alias so you can write `static T pmf;`? Also note that `throw()` was deprecated in C++11 and is removed for C++20, and means `noexcept` in C++17.

Comment: @Barry I want to know which compiler is correct. And thank you recommend about `throw()`

Comment: I can’t reproduce this (with [GCC 7.3.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LFYkKw5ha6CvgEcA) or a few more recent versions).

Comment: @eddiekuo are you sure you're using the exact same flags for compilation?  Because I'm not

Comment: Well, I'm no "language lawyer," but it seems to me that `clang` is correct here (and `MSVC` also gives the warning). Easy to remove though (deprecation of `throw()` notwithstanding), with: `void (A::* A::pmf)() throw () = &A::g;` in your definition, so that it *actually matches* the declaration.

Comment: @Chipster `pmf` is declared as a static pointer-to-function, as in (e.g.): `void (*fncptr)(void);`.

Comment: @LTPCGO I use -O0 -S option to compile

Comment: @eddiekuo I meant go into the documentation and look at what flags are set by default and what options are used.  Compilers don't all do the same thing out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while I was writing a cpp program to implement stack with exception handling.
I was creating a class using template:

```
template <class T>
class Stack{
private:
    T *stk;
    T size;
    int top;
public:
    Stack(){
        top = -1;
        size = 1;
    }
    void push(T data);         // definition
    void create(T size);
    void pop();
};     
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(int data){//error line due to differ datatypes in declaration and definition
    try{
        if(top == --size)
            throw StackOverflow();
        top++;
        stk[top] = data;
        cout<<"\nData is inserted : "<<stk[top];
    }
    catch(StackOverflow){
        cout<<"\nStack overflowed";
    }
}
```

I was getting the same error because I have declared this in the class:

```
void push(T data);
```

and this in definition of the function:

```
void Stack<T>::push(int data)
```

Definitely the function signature that I declared inside the class and then defining outside the class are different. That's why that error was occurring.

So I matched both of them accordingly:

```
void push(T data); 
void Stack<T>::push(T data)
```

This solved my error and program compiled successfully.